# Swift, load video of the gallery without compression

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

When you offer the possibility to a user to use a video previously registered in the gallery of the iPhone with a `UIImagePickerController`, it's imported and compressed to 1280x720 regardless of the original resolution. Is it possible to get the original video at the original quality with `UIImagePickerController` ?

The url returned by `UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL` seem to be a temporary url to the compressed file, so not usable to get the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can think of for that problem. First, there is a property of `UIImagePickerController` called `videoExportPreset`. You can set that property to `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`.

> **videoExportPreset** can be used to specify the transcoding quality for
>   videos (via a AVAssetExportPreset* string). If the value is nil (the
>   default) then the transcodeQuality is determined by videoQuality
>   instead. Not valid if the source type is
>   `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`.

Remember to do `import AVFoundation`.

---

Second way is to implement your own picker, that is, using **PHAsset**.

Example:

```
 let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: nil)

 let videoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
 videoRequestOptions.version = .original

 fetchResult.enumerateObjects { (asset, index, _) in
     PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: videoRequestOptions) { (avAsset, audioMix, infoDic) in
         //----
     }
 }
```

Comment: I didn't saw the ```videoExportPreset``` property, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can set AVCaptureSession.Preset according to your need.

```
var session: AVCaptureSession?

func video(){

        // Don't trigger camera access for the background
    guard AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) == .authorized else {
        return
    }

    do {
        // Prepare avcapture session
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        session?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high //medium or low

        // Hook upp device
        let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)
        session?.addInput(input)

        // Setup capture layer

        guard session != nil else {
            return
        }

        let captureLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session!)
        captureLayer.frame = bounds
        captureLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraBackground.layer.addSublayer(captureLayer)

        self.captureLayer = captureLayer
    } catch {
        session = nil
    }
}
```